# string type not allowed at <data android:type="*/*" />

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set the filter on my app, so I can listen to my diferent email applications, but I always get the error: "`String type not allowed at <data android:type="*/*" />`"

How can I change that so it can listen to all my email apps, and how can I change it so I can listen to a specific app and not all applications?

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.filipecosta.mytasks">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".TaskActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <data android:type="*/*" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <data android:scheme="mailto" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PhoneCall"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no attribute `type` for `<data>`. Just use `android:mimeType` instead of `android:type`

**Try this:**

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

For details: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no attribute `type` in  for

Just `mimeType`.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html?hl=en-419

Answer (score -1):

[`<data>` has no `android:type`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)

I think you want MIME type, so `android:mimeType="*/*"`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15647129)

Comment: @manniL Look at the other answers and tell me how this isn't the same information?